# How to add sequence number for groups in a SQL query without temp tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, grouping

I've created a complex search query in SQL 2008 that returns data sorted by groups, and the query itself has paging and sorting functions in it, but rather than returning a set number of records based on the paging options, it needs to return a set number of groups (so the number of records will vary).

I'm currently doing this through the use of Temp Tables (the first temp table creates a list of the Groups that will be selected as part of the search, and then numbers them... and the second query joins this table to the actual search... so, it ends up running the search query twice).

What I'm looking for is a more efficient way to do this using some of the new functions in SQL 2008 (which wouldn't require the use of temp tables).

If I can get the data in a format like this, I'd be set...

```
Record  Group     GroupSequence
-------|---------|--------------
1       Chickens  1
2       Chickens  1
3       Cows      2
4       Horses    3
5       Horses    3
6       Horses    3
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this with a single query in SQL 2008, without using temp tables?

Comment: Which columns are from data and which need the values calculated?

Comment: The first and second columns ("Record[Number]" and "Group") are from data.  The column "GroupSequence" would be calculated by the query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sample data

```
create table sometable([group] varchar(10), id int, somedata int)
insert sometable select 'Horses', 9, 11
insert sometable select 'chickens', 19, 121
insert sometable select 'Horses', 29, 123
insert sometable select 'chickens', 49, 124
insert sometable select 'Cows', 98, 1
insert sometable select 'Horses', 99, 2
```

Query

```
select
    Record = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [Group], id),
    [Group],
    GroupSequence = DENSE_RANK() over (order by [Group])
from sometable
```

Output

```
Record               Group      GroupSequence
-------------------- ---------- --------------------
1                    chickens   1
2                    chickens   1
3                    Cows       2
4                    Horses     3
5                    Horses     3
6                    Horses     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Without more details about the tables you have, I'd say look into [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) queries and the [row_number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function... something along the lines of:

```
;with groups as (
  select top 10 name, row_number() over(order by name) 'sequence'
  from table1
  group by name
  order by name
)
select row_number() over(order by g.name) 'Record',
  g.name 'GroupName',
  g.sequence 'GroupSequence'
from groups
```

Comment: For the purposes of pagination, I've modified most of my search queries to use this new "with <table_name> as" notation, which does appear to run much faster than either @ or # temp tables.

Comment: Be careful, because that isn't always going to be true.  The `with` query notation, in this usage, is like a named subquery (which can be used several times)... so sometimes, a temp table or table variable will be better options.