# How to add sequence number for each element in a group using a SQL query without temp tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, grouping, running-count

My question is quite similar to the one posted in this link - [How to add sequence number for groups in a SQL query without temp tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253311/how-to-add-sequence-number-for-groups-in-a-sql-query-without-temp-tables)

But, I need to enumerate the occurrence of group. The final output to be like this:

| Record | Group | GroupSequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chickens | 1 |
| 2 | Chickens | 2 |
| 3 | Cows | 1 |
| 4 | Horses | 1 |
| 5 | Horses | 2 |
| 6 | Horses | 3 |

Plus this has to be done in Oracle SQL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY Record) AS GroupSequence1,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY Record) AS GroupSequence2,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY Record) AS GroupSequence3,
    Table1.Group,
    Table1.Record
FROM
    Table1
```

`GroupSequence1`, `GroupSequence2` and `GroupSequence3` will get you the output you want.