# Populate Sequence Number by Repeated fields in Coloumns

Tags: sql-server

i have below data in my table

```
  description    id
--------------  ------
    desc1         0
    desc2         0
    desc3         0
    desc4         1
    desc5         1
    desc6         1
```

I need below

```
  description    id       sequenceNo
--------------  ------   ------------------
    desc1         0         1
    desc2         0         2
    desc3         0         3
    desc4         1         1
    desc5         1         2
    desc6         1         3
```

Please let me know how to solve this query by using sql function or any other alternative..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add sequence number for each element in a group using a SQL query without temp tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244594/how-to-add-sequence-number-for-each-element-in-a-group-using-a-sql-query-without)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select *,ROW_NUMBER() Over(partition By ID order by ID asc)
as sequenceNo from Mytable
```