# Add a sequence number to each element in a group using python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, running-count

I have a dataframe of individuals who each have multiple records.  I want to enumerate the record in the sequence for each individual in python.  Essentially I would like to create the 'sequence' column in the following table:

```
patient  date      sequence
145      20Jun2009        1
145      24Jun2009        2
145      15Jul2009        3
582      09Feb2008        1
582      21Feb2008        2
987      14Mar2010        1
987      02May2010        2
987      12May2010        3
```

This is essentially the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244594/how-to-add-sequence-number-for-each-element-in-a-group-using-a-sql-query-without), but I am working in python and unable to implement the sql solution. I suspect I can use a groupby statement with an iterable count, but have so far been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is how do I sort on multiple columns of data.

One simple trick is to use the `key` parameter to the [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function.

You'll be sorting by a string built from the columns of the array.

```
rows = ...# your source data

def date_to_sortable_string(date):
  # use datetime package to convert string to sortable date.
  pass

# Assume x[0] === patient_id and x[1] === encounter date

# Sort by patient_id and date
rows_sorted = sorted(rows, key=lambda x: "%0.5d-%s" % (x[0], date_to_sortable_string(x[1])))

for row in rows_sorted:
  print row
```

Answer (score 69):

I stumbled upon the answer which was embarrassingly simple. The groupby statement has a 'cumcount()' option which will enumerate group items.

```
df['sequence']=df.groupby('patient').cumcount()
```

The caveat is that the records have to be in the order you want them enumerated.

Comment: If the sequence column is supposed to be in date order then this might fail. It is relying on the dataframe to already be sorted which is a big assumption.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the sequence to be **sorted** based on the values of another column, first sort the dataframe and then add the new sequence column.

For instance, if we want the sequence for patients visits sorted based on their visit date, the following code can be used.

```
df['sequence'] = df.sort_values(by=['patient', 'date']).groupby('patient']).cumcount() + 1
```

Answer (score 4):

This will start orderings starting at 1 instead of 0.

```
df['sequence']=df.groupby('patient').cumcount()+1
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you want to convert the date column to be a pandas datetime (rather than strings):

```
In [11]: pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y')
Out[11]:
0   2009-06-20
1   2009-06-24
2   2009-07-15
3   2008-02-09
4   2008-02-21
5   2010-03-14
6   2010-05-02
7   2010-05-12
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

*Note: see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for possible format options.*

```
In [12]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y')

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   patient       date  sequence
0      145 2009-06-20         1
1      145 2009-06-24         2
2      145 2009-07-15         3
3      582 2008-02-09         1
4      582 2008-02-21         2
5      987 2010-03-14         1
6      987 2010-05-02         2
7      987 2010-05-12         3
```

If this isn't in date order (for each patient), I would sort it first:

```
In [14]: df = df.sort('date')
```

Now you can groupby and cumcount:

```
In [15]: g = df.groupby('patient')

In [16]: g.cumcount() + 1
Out[16]:
2    1
3    2
0    1
1    2
4    1
5    2
6    3
dtype: int64
```

Which is what you want (althout it's out of order):

```
In [17]: df['sequence'] = g.cumcount() + 1

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
       patient       date  sequence
2      582 2008-02-09         1
3      582 2008-02-21         2
0      145 2009-06-24         1
1      145 2009-07-15         2
4      987 2010-03-14         1
5      987 2010-05-02         2
6      987 2010-05-12         3
```

To rearrange (though you may not need to) use `sort_index` (or we could reindex if we saved the initial DataFrame's index):*

```
In [19]: df.sort_index()
Out[19]:
   patient       date  sequence
0      145 2009-06-24         1
1      145 2009-07-15         2
2      582 2008-02-09         1
3      582 2008-02-21         2
4      987 2010-03-14         1
5      987 2010-05-02         2
6      987 2010-05-12         3
```